# Return all whole words in a string upto a given index

Tags: python, split, substring

lets say I have this string which is 42 characters

```
**
0         1         2       *2*  3         4
0123456789012345678901234567*8*90123456789012
The quick brown fox jumps ov*e*r the lazy dog
**
```

I want to use it as a search query where the search query can not be longer than 28 characters this i would do by

`searchQuery = myString[:28]` returning >> The quick brown fox jumps ove

however, I would like it to return *The quick brown fox jumps* as those are the whole words in the returned string

Answer (score 1):

Look for the last index of a whitespace via `str.rindex`, then slice on that:

```
def whole_words_upto(string, index): 
    return string[:string[:index].rindex(' ')]


whole_words_upto('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 28)
# 'The quick brown fox jumps'
```

Note: Does not handle erroneous input or corner cases (that's your task ;-).

---

A second option is to split and iterate, checking the cumulative length of words before returning:

```
def whole_words_upto(string, index): 
    total_len = 0
    words = string.split()
    for i, s in enumerate(words):
        if i > 0 and total_len + len(s) >= index:
            return ' '.join(words[:i-1])
        total_len += len(s)

    return string
```

Comment: I sort of went with something like the first option, but oh my yours is a simple one liner beauty! However, you mention a corner case... What's that?
Thank you for you help!

Comment: @JasonHudson Empty strings, sentences with one word, etc etc. Essentially inputs that you don't usually see but should still account for.